# Redshift creating a new column with static string error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

How my query is implemented i use a statement like `SELECT 'ChickenMongoose' as animal` to create a new column with the static word of "ChickenMongoose" However I get this error from redshift `Value too long for type character varying(7)` How can I create a new column with a static string that would accomodate this length?

more context:

```
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'ChickenMongoose' as animal ,
       SUM(COALESCE(friends.touches, 0)) AS touches
       FROM
        basic t
       INNER JOIN
        mock_friends friends ON friends.initiative_id = t.initiative_id
       WHERE
       'ChickenMongoose' in ('ChickenMongoose', 'potato')
```

basically my queries are connected with union ALLS with one select statement at the top, and it is not allowing me to assign ChickenMongoose as a static name under the column animal

Thank you

Comment: A `select` should not be generating that error.  Are you storing this in a table?

Comment: sorry let me provide more context

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift, try replacing your last line
`'ChickenMongoose' in ('ChickenMongoose', 'potato')`
with
`animal in ('ChickenMongoose', 'potato')`

since it would treat this as a non-integer character constant